# How can I set the tint color of a MPVolumeView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, media-player, uislider, mpvolumeview

How can I set the tint color of a MPVolumeView?

I see the method:

```
setMinimumTrackTintColor:
```

and the property

```
minimumTrackTintColor
```

however using either of those throws an exception.

I was told I need to call

```
setMinimumTintColor
```

or set the property

```
minimumTrackTintColor
```

on the underlying UISlider, however I don't know how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget that it's not just an underlying UISlider - there's also a route button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In iOS 7 you simply can change the slider color of a `MPVolumeView` like this:

```
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(17, 45, 220, 0);
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];

volumeView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:127.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I don't know how I missed that property before :P

Comment: While this works, it's not complete.  The route button doesn't use the tint.

Answer (score 3):

I have searched for answer to this for a very long time, because in my app I need to set volumeView colors dynamically. Since UISlider provides a way to change its tint color, you can cycle through MPVolumeView subviews until you find an instance of UISlider class and then operate on this one.

Here is the code in Swift:

```
func customSlider() {
        let temp = mpVolView.subviews
        for current in temp {
            if current.isKind(of: UISlider.self) {
                let tempSlider = current as! UISlider
                tempSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = .yellow
                tempSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = .blue
            }
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to change the route button color too:

```
volumeView.tintColor = .green
if let routeButton = volumeView.subviews.compactMap({ $0 as? UIButton }).first,
    let image = routeButton.image(for: .normal) {
    routeButton.setImage(image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: [])
}
```